# [System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines adds newline at the end

Tags: file, shell, powershell, newline

I have this code:

```
# Generate bash script
$bashScript = "#!/bin/bash`n";
$bashScript += [string]::Join("`n", $cmds)

[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($location.ToString() + ".\build.sh", $bashScript);
```

The problem is that I always get `CRLF` characters at the end of the file!

```
#!/bin/bash [LF]
tsc ... [LF]
java ... [LF]
java ... [CR][LF]
```

Is there anything I can do except replacing `CRLF` at the end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't speak Powershell, but it seems to me that you've told it to write one big line (`$bash_script`) with a newline (CRLF) at the end. Call [`WriteAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx) instead. Be sure to have a LF at the end of the file.

```
$bashScript = "#!/bin/bash`n" + [string]::Join("`n", $cmds) + "`n"
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText($location.ToString() + ".\build.sh", $bashScript);
```